# php: Textarea HTML value to show in Html Email?

Tags: html, email, textarea, php

I'm using PHPmailer and everything is perfect except the Texts inside `<textarea>` are showing as ONE SINGLE LINE. Meaning, no html value (for only TEXTAREA) at all.

- Actually **the mail itself is HTML already**.
- I can embed Images.. etc as well.
- Just the `<textarea>` is not working.

I am using this:

```
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Body = $_POST['textarea'];
```

Lets say the `<textarea>` contains something like:

```
Hello,
How are you.

Best Wishes,
4lvin
```

Then in the email, it is showing just like:

```
Hello, How are you. Best Wishes, 4lvin
```

Any idea please? :(

Comment: what \n please? I mean, the `<textarea>` values should be going out as HTML automatically rite?

Comment: just use htmlentities($_POST['textarea']);

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use

```
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Body = nl2br($_POST['textarea']);
```