# how to display textarea field in html?

Tags: php, html, mysql

hi i inserted some data to mysql through textarea.in that i added content like this

```
Test
test2
1) tch
2) ECE
```

display in textarea also coming like above only.but when coming to the HTML display it is showwing.

```
Test  test2 1) tch 2) ECE
```

what to do in that time to display correctly.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13816746/php-textarea-html-value-to-show-in-html-email/

Answer (score 2):

use **nl2br(values of textarea)** function.

Answer (score 1):

the `\n` aren't displayed in HTML, you should replace all your `\r`, `\r\n` and `\n` for `<br/>`

Comment: actually, the `\n` is displayed in a `<textarea>` element. **Edit**: sorry, I misread the question, you're absolutely right.

Answer (score 1):

[nl2br](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) is the function you need

> Returns string with <br / > or '<br>' inserted before all newlines (\r\n, \n\r, \n and \r).

Answer (score 1):

You can add `<br/>` tags (using for example `nl2br` function), but in this case you can reach another problem - tabs or multiply spaces will be displayed as single space and striped from the line beginnings.

Second solution is to use `<pre>` tag.

```
<pre>Test
test2
1) tech
2) ECE</pre>
```

probably you'll need to style it a little bit as it uses monospace font by default and does not wrap text, but you can easily change it using css.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the '\n' character to return from line:

Example:

```
echo "<textarea>" . "Line 01\nLine 02" . "</textarea>";
```